# Form's reset() method doesn't reset input with value attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Why second input with value attribute not being reset when I call the form's `reset()` method? And what is the best way to clean a form which has inputs with value attributes?

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <button id="reset" name="reset" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').reset()">reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: DId you forget to put `myform` as ID in the above code?

Comment: @Huangism yes I did. But still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript here. Just set the `type` attribute of the button to `reset`.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <button id="reset" name="reset" type="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

By default, a `button` element within a `form` will submit the form.

Comment: But input with value "1" not being reseted. That is the thing.

Comment: It works in Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10. I type anything into the `input` with "1", click the reset button, and it's back to "1"...

Comment: I expected it to be cleared to empty value, not back to 1. But seems like it does not work this way.

Comment: Then don't set the value to 1, it resets to the value of the input

Comment: Yes, the `value` attribute sets the "default value" of the `input` for HTML's purposes. If you want it cleared completely, you will need to use JavaScript and explicitly set the value to the empty string. There is no shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery

```js
$("#reset").on("click" , function() {
   $("input[type=text]").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <button id="reset" name="reset" type="button">reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset button reset form to *initial* values, not empty values. If you want to reset form completely, you should use empty form and then set values manually after form is placed to document. For example, apply ids to field you want to preset and then use something like

```js
const filedValues = [{
    id: 'name',
    value: '1'
  },
  {
    id: 'text',
    value: 'test text'
  }
];
filedValues.forEach(fieldItem => {
  const {
    id,
    value
  } = fieldItem;
  document.getElementById(id).value = value;
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
  <button id="reset" name="reset" type="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one line code:

```
this.form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach(function(input,i){input.value='';})
```

See:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="0"/>
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <button id="reset" name="reset" onclick="this.form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach(function(input,i){input.value='';})">reset</button>
</form>
```

**Note**: no need to add `type=reset` to `button`